# Wordpress stylesheet include not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have coded a custom site, and am using Wordpress to host. Currently, I'm trying to only link index.php and style.css. All I get is either a blank page or the html without css. CSS is the same directory as index.php. What am I doing wrong? I've been trying everything.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Goats for Sale | Clayson Ridge Farm</title>
<meta name="description" content="High-quality, purebred goats by Clayson Ridge Farm. Prize-winning Alpine and Nubian goats for sale. We ship all across Canada. Reserve your goat today." />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" media="screen" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Comment: What is rendered at the `<link>` line in the HTML?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Gotta dumb it down a shade.

Comment: When your server renders your PHP file, when you get to the URL, open up the HTML source and see what's there. Try to work from that. It's not the answer in your mouth like below, but you get +1 skill in debugging! ;o)

Comment: Thanks! Teach a man to fish and all that :P. That's awesome man.

Comment: You may want to look into using https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style. Also, you're working on a site that sells goats? That's awesome.

Comment: I don't understand any of that coding for Function Reference. I am not even slightly good at php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i thing you use `stylesheet_url`

```
admin_email          = admin@example.com
atom_url             = http://www.example.com/home/feed/atom
charset              = UTF-8
comments_atom_url    = http://www.example.com/home/comments/feed/atom
comments_rss2_url    = http://www.example.com/home/comments/feed
description          = Just another WordPress blog
home                 = http://www.example.com/home (DEPRECATED! use url option instead)
html_type            = text/html
language             = en-US
name                 = Testpilot
pingback_url         = http://www.example.com/home/wp/xmlrpc.php
rdf_url              = http://www.example.com/home/feed/rdf
rss2_url             = http://www.example.com/home/feed
rss_url              = http://www.example.com/home/feed/rss
siteurl              = http://www.example.com/home (DEPRECATED! use url option instead)
stylesheet_directory = http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/largo
stylesheet_url       = http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/largo/style.css
template_directory   = http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/largo
template_url         = http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/largo
text_direction       = ltr
url                  = http://www.example.com/home
version              = 3.5
wpurl                = http://www.example.com/home/wp
```

Replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" media="screen" />
```

get_stylesheet_directory_uri() => this return your template directory path than you need style.css.